Converting cyclic DiGraph to Acyclic DiGraph (DAG)
How can I remove cycles from my directed graph? It's a big graph (100k+ nodes 200k+ edges) so the method needs to be efficient. I need to make the digraph acyclic in order to use functions like networkx.topological_generations.
I've tried methods where I repeatedly generate cycles and remove the last edge in each cycle path but after running for 10+ hours without finishing I considered this a failed attempt.
failed attempt (never finished; inefficient)
def remove_cycles_from_G(G: nx.DiGraph):
    search_for_cycles = True
    while search_for_cycles:
        for cycle_path in nx.simple_cycles(G):
            try:
                G.remove_edge(cycle_path[-1], cycle_path[0])
            except nx.NetworkXError:
                # edge has already been disjointed by a previous edge removal.
                # Restart cycle generator.
                search_for_cycles = (
                    False  # Temporary condition which will be reversed.
                )
                break
        search_for_cycles = not (search_for_cycles)

I've also crafted a more sophisticated heuristic approach based on the demonstrations in this project but even this method doesn't work on a digraph of this size (after an hour of running my memory was maxed out).
I understand that identifying the fewest edges to remove in order to make the digraph acyclic is an NP-hard problem (feedback arc set problem) but I'm not necessarily trying to find the fewest edges to make the digraph acyclic, I just want a fast and efficient approach.
EDIT: reproducible input data
Here's an example of a networkx DiGraph with a ton of cycles. My situation involves even more but this demonstrates the point:
import networkx as nx
import random

def induce_cycles(g: nx.DiGraph, cycles) -> None:
    cycles_added = 0
    while cycles_added < cycles:
        node = random.choice(list(g))
        non_parent_ancestors = nx.ancestors(g, node).difference(g.predecessors(node))
        if non_parent_ancestors:
            g.add_edge(node, random.choice(list(non_parent_ancestors)))
            cycles_added += 1

g = nx.balanced_tree(3, 6, create_using=nx.DiGraph())
induce_cycles(g, len(g.edges()) * 5)

# Efficiently remove cycles from g...


(The discussion that got us here was acrimonious. I'm leaving only the good bits for anyone who needs this answer in the future.)
Here is a different approach. I'm trying to imitate a topological sort, EXCEPT that I'm taking the approach of always finding a best next one.
from sortedcontainers import SortedSet

def topological_remove_cycles (g):
    # Dictionary of sets of incoming edges. We want to pick nodes with few of them.
    incoming = {}
    for node in g.nodes:
        incoming[node] = set()
    for node in g.nodes():
        for next_node in g.neighbors(node):
            incoming[next_node].add(node)

    # Sorted set of (count_incoming, -count_outgoing, node) triplets.
    # The first item in the set will have as few incoming nodes as it can, and as many outgoing.
    # In other words, it is a greedy choice for a good node to get rid of cycles.
    todo = SortedSet()
    for node, to_node in incoming.items():
        todo.add((len(to_node), -len(g.adj[node]), node))

    # And now let's start removing cycles.
    while 0 < len(todo):
        # Get the best node.
        _, _, node = todo.pop(0)
        to_node = incoming[node]
        for prev_node in to_node:
            # Each of these edges is in, or comes from, a cycle.
            if prev_node != node:
                # Do bookkeeping in todo.
                len_in = len(incoming[prev_node])
                len_out = len(g.adj[prev_node])
                todo.remove((len_in, -len_out, prev_node))
                todo.add((len_in, -len_out + 1, prev_node))
            g.remove_edge(prev_node, node)

        for next_node in g.neighbors(node):
            # Do bookkeeping in todo for forgetting about node.
            len_in = len(incoming[next_node])
            len_out = len(g.adj[next_node])
            todo.remove((len_in, -len_out, next_node))
            todo.add((len_in - 1, -len_out, next_node))
            incoming[next_node].remove(node)
        # And now we've guaranteed that node is cycle free and gone from our bookkeeping.

And of course, let's do a small test where the previous code failed.
data = {0: [1, 2, 11], 1: [3, 4, 10], 2: [5, 6], 3: [7, 8, 6, 9], 4: [9, 10], 5: [11, 12, 3], 6: [13, 14, 10, 5, 7], 7: [1], 8: [7, 14], 9: [10], 10: [14], 11: [10], 12: [], 13: [], 14: [1, 2]}
g = nx.from_dict_of_lists(data, create_using=nx.DiGraph())

print(nx.to_dict_of_lists(g))
print(g)
print("Before removing, there are " + str(len(list(nx.simple_cycles(g)))) + " cycles")
topological_remove_cycles(g)
print(g)
print("After removing, there are " + str(len(list(nx.simple_cycles(g)))) + " cycles")
print(nx.to_dict_of_lists(g))

And a larger test. Note that it is so good at untangling things, it usually finds a way to remove fewer edges than were added in creating cycles!
g = nx.balanced_tree(3, 6, create_using=nx.DiGraph())
induce_cycles(g, 100)
print(g)
topological_remove_cycles(g)
print(g)
print("After removing, there are " + str(len(list(nx.simple_cycles(g)))) + " cycles")


Thanks for demonstrating that method. But fast_remove_cycles doesn't work in all cases. Try a case with induce_cycles(g, 100) (or even a larger number of cycles if your pc can handle it) and you'll see that after running it there are still cycles left. I've tried to follow through your code to figure out why but I can't identify what could be the problem.

@russhoppa There is now a fixed version that should work much better. It runs in O(n log(n)). But for that you get a greedy attempt at finding a small minimal feedback arc set.

VERY impressive. Thank you for putting that together. The usage of that SortedSet type is great. I didn't know about that library.

@russhoppa Yea, it's great. I got to stop handrolling slower ways to do that. Incidentally I got rid of some of the past unpleasantness from the post. Just leaving the useful answer for the future.

Thank you, looks great. And I apologize about those. I do have one question about your method that I can't understand. Where you write the comment, # Each of these edges is in, or comes from, a cycle. how can you make the assumption that the nodes as sorted with least predecessors and most successors are in a cycle? Just because a node has few predecessors and many successors it doesn't definitely mean it's part of a cycle, right? Or is this just a naive assumption of the algorithm which happens to be right most of the time?

@russhoppa Not naive. :) If there is any node which is not kept alive by a cycle, then there is a node with no incoming edges. That will be selected first. So we can only get incoming edges  on our node when everything is kept alive by cycles.

After I wrote it, I thought about working from the min of incoming and outgoing. That will do better than this, at the cost of some complexity. But I'd already written it, and I don't know what improvement it would cause.

I see. That's an effective sort.
